# core modem/router connections for server

Tags: connection, windows-server-2008, switch, adsl

In our lan network we have a netgear adsl modem/router which connects to network switch and server also connects to this switch.

I just wanted to know if we could connect our server 2008 to the adsl modem/router ,so a port is freed up in the switch . Will there be any negative effect in the network please.

Comment: This question is way to broad.  It sounds like you need a switch with more ports.

Comment: I partly agree with Ramhound - I'm not convinced a bigger switch is needed, but you really should specify the make and model of the router and switch otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: The network has around 100 pcs ,printers .....We use a netgear dgn2200 adsl modem router with 4 ports. and dlink 24 port switch

Comment: If the network has 100 devices it must have more then a 24 port switch + adsl modem-router.  As this router only has 100 megabit ports, and is not really designe for large environments, its probably a good idea to get another gigabit switch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its a small office/consumer grade router - which sounds likely, this should work.

Depending on the quality and design of the router, you may or may not notice decreased network performance.   Some routers have a built in 4 port switch while others have independent ports of which are made to appear as a switch using software.   If the router has independent ports then the throughput (number of packets per second) of the router will be governed by the speed of the processor, but if its a built in switch, then it will be similar to any other switch of a similar speed.

The easiest way is to try it and see - other then a brief outage when you plug and unplug it, there should not be a noticeable outage where things need to reconfigure.

Comment: The network has around 100 pcs ,printers .....We use a netgear dgn2200 adsl modem router with 4 ports. and dlink 24 port switch.